# Problema con Socket.io - Funciona sólo en local

Tags: nodejs, express, servidor, socket.io, cpanel

Tengo dramas con una aplicación simple creada con Socket.io y algo de Express sobre NodeJs. Lo que me complica es que al lanzarlo de manera local (localhost), me funciona perfectamente, pero si lo subo a un servidor con Cpanel y NodeJs incluido, la aplicación lanza 2 problemas.

1) El primero es este:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                          socket.io.js:1
>
> Uncaugth ReferenceError: io is not defined at main.js:1 
>                                        main.js:1

2) Después cambia a estos errores:

> GET http://pagina_prueba.cl/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)       pagina_prueba.cl/:6
>
> Uncaugth ReferenceError: io is not defined at main.js:1 
>                                        main.js:1

Sinceramente no sé qué puede ser... He probado con diferentes rutas en el script de socket.io en el html, pero sigue dando los mismos errores.
Las carpetas están en:

> pagina_prueba.cl/VCON
>
> > node_modules
> >
> > public
> >
> > > index.html
> > >
> > > main.js
> >
> > server
> >
> > > main.js
> >
> > package.json

server/main.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server  = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var messages=[{
        id: 1,
        text: "Hola! Soy un mensaje de prueba",
        author: "Anonimo"
}];

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.status(200).send("Hola Mundo LOL");
});

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log("Alguien se ha conectado con Socket");
    socket.emit('messages', messages);

    socket.on('new-message', function(data){
        messages.push(data);
    io.sockets.emit('messages', messages);
    });
});

server.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Servidor corriendo en :8080 xD');
});
```

public/index.html

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Mi aplicacion de prueba</title>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My App</h1>
        <div id="messages"></div>
    <br>
        <form onsubmit="return addMessage(this)">
            <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Tu nombre">
            <input type="text" id="texto" placeholder="Escribe Algo">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar!">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

public/main.js

```
socket.on('messages', function(data){
    console.log(data);
    render(data);
});

function render(data) {
    var html = data.map(function(elem,index){
        return(`<div>
                    <strong>${elem.author} </strong>
                    <em>${elem.text}</em>
                </div>`);
    }).join(" ");
    document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = html;
}

function addMessage(e){
    var payload = {
        author: document.getElementById('username').value,
        text: document.getElementById('texto').value
    };

    socket.emit('new-message', payload);
    return false;
}
```

Pido ayuda!

Actualización: Revisando y probando, al parecer puede que sea que los puertos con los que estoy probando estén cerrados en el servidor con el que trabajo, si alguien me pudiese confirmar si ese problema me daría ese tipo de errores sería genial...

ACTUALIZACION:
Agrego imágenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si es que me salto la restricción de puertos de Chrome con el comando --explicitly-allowed-ports=587, me aparece lo siguiente por consola:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: ok, dices que tu aplicacion se despliega perfectamente pero lo unico que da el error es socket.io?

Comment: Al subirla al servidor me da sólo esos errores mostrados, ninguno más...

Comment: La verdad he estado experimentando con varias aplicaciones y todas me han funcionado en local, pero al subirlas dan este tipo de errores, todas me dan el mismo para ser un poco más específico, y leyendo en foros no he dado con alguna respuesta o solución que pueda ayudarme

Comment: He consultado con el servidor y tengo los puertos que puedo utilizar, ahora sin embargo me lanza otro error: 
index.js:83 GET https://www.pagina_prueba.cl:587/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N6JCH_E net::ERR_UNSAFE_PORT

Comment: Por lo que he leído, tiene que ver con que es un puerto declarado inseguro por chrome, pero si lo abro con otro navegador (Edge por ejemplo), no muestra errores hasta que trato de enviar un mensaje. Si trato de enviar algo, muestra en consola:
CONSOLE21301: Se rechaza serviceWorker.getRegistrations debido a contexto no seguro o restricción del host en file:///C:/Windows/SystemApps/Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe/Assets/WebNotes/WebNotesContent.htm?pic=1&fileid={CA3CCE04-DF05-4786-8333-A4F3CD35B89D}

Comment: ¿Tiene que ver con la configuración de los puertos en el server?¿El tipo de puerto?
¿Hay alguna clase de verificación que pueda hacerse para que deje de considerar como inseguro los puertos?

Comment: ¿Quizá debo pedir que abran un puerto específico bajo un protocolo en particular?

Comment: en tu main.js no se ve que hayas iniciado socket.io, lo has iniciado y no lo has mostrado?

Comment: Cuando quito el puerto 587 de los unsafe port en Chrome, sale Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR... 
Creo que si entonces es una cosa de protocolos de puerto y restricciones de seguridad... ¿Qué protocolos debe tener el puerto? ¿TCP/UDP? 
Así podría pedir que abran un puerto con esas configuraciones y lograr dar por terminado el tema xD
Se les agradece mucho su ayuda chic@s, pese a que aún no me funciona, me siento apoyado y que aprendo cada momento algo nuevo :)

Comment: ¿iniciar socket.io en server/main o public/main?
(Para el siguiente proyecto le pongo nombres más distintivos, lo prometo xD)

Comment: lo pudiste solucionar?

Comment: @Enzo aún no... Pero es eso? Debo pedir un puerto TCP/UDP con una numeración fuera de la lista de unsafe por de Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un par de cosas que parecen fallar:

**Primero**: estas sirviendo mal el archivo html o por lo menos no de la manera ideal, ¿cual es el punto de trabajar con un servidor web que te sirve html estático?.

Recomiendo que crees una carpeta views en la raíz e introduzcas ahí tus HTML (***views***), luego con `express` en tu respuesta de `app.get("/")` en lugar de enviar `res.status(200).send("Hola Mundo LOL")` envia el archivo directamente, `res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html")`. Utiliza el directorio estático para acceder a tus assets y no a tus páginas.

**Segundo**: no puedo ver que estes declarando la variable `express` en ninguna parte de tu app, puede que haya sido un error de transcripción, ya que la app te funciona, pero todo cuenta.

**Tercero:** hay una mal llamado del método `createServer()` del módulo http.

Intenta declarar tu servidor de la siguiente manera:

```
const app = require('express')(); // Ó const express = require('express'), app = expres()
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   console.log("Alguien se ha conectado con Socket");
  socket.emit('messages', messages);

  socket.on('new-message', function(data){
   messages.push(data);
   io.sockets.emit('messages', messages);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

> **Nota que** cando declaras el servidor http el método es `createServer(app)` **y no** `Server(app);`

Prueba y me dices como te va, un saludo y espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por las acotaciones! 
Edité el comentario del código porque efectivamente me comí una línea al traspasar...
Reordene un poco las cosas y creo que seguiré tu consejo y trataré de hacer todo más dinámico. Sin embargo, sigue sin funcionar: Ahora lanza otro error:
GET http://www.pagina_prueba.cl:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N6A100e net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT 
index.js:83 
Y si presiono el index.js:83  me muestra la siguiente linea:
this.jitter = jitter;(Comentario: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)...

Comment: Probé con otros puertos y me salen algunos errores diferentes... Por ejemplo en el 8080 sale net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED y un error que dice XHR failed loading: GET "<URL>"... Cada vez siento que aprendo más, pero a su vez aparecen muchas más cosas que no comprendo. Si sabes qué me puede estar provocando ese error te lo agradecería muchisimo, sino, igual te agradezco el tiempo por ya haberme ayudado bastante amigo!

Comment: Ingresa la ruta de la librería de socket que importas en el lado del cliente en el navegador y avísame que pone.

Comment: Disculpa mi falta de conocimiento... ¿Cuál sería la ruta? 
¿Sería www.pagina_prueba.cl//socket.io/socket.io.js?

Comment: Correcto /socket.io/socket.io.js, Tambien intenta ingresar a otrosarchivos en el directorio publico, como el css etc a ver que carga, si te cargan los estilos el directorio publico está funcionando.

Comment: Puedes adjuntar captura de tus sources en las herramienta de desarrollo de tu navegador?

Comment: Al poner la ruta de socket.io en la barra de direcciones aparece un texto gigante que empieza por /*!
 * Socket.IO v2.3.0
 * (c) 2014-2019 Guillermo Rauch
 * Released under the MIT License.
 */
!function(t,e){"object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module?module.exports=e():......

Comment: Amigo eso significa que está funcionando el problema de alguna manera está siendo ocasionado en la importación de socket en el HTML

Comment: Me sirvieron todas las correcciones que mencionaste y de hecho solucionan el problema... Sin embargo, al final no funcionaba debido a que los puertos estaban bloqueados en el servidor y por alguna que otra letra chica no me los abrieron, así que vamos a cambiar de servicio. 
Se agradece su ayuda compañero!
Doy por solucionada mi duda al respecto :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, si tu dices que tu aplicación se despliega perfectamente pero solamente te da el error de socket.io yo diría que modifiques un poco tu código, ejemplo:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()

app.use('port', process.env.PORT || 8080)
```

//aquí lo que se hace es generar una variable donde guardar el puerto y se lee de la siguiente manera,
 cuando una app esta en producción el servicio de hosting te da un puerto por defecto, eso se obtiene desde process.env.PORT, entonces seria, usa el puerto existente que te da el hosting, en caso de que no exista usa el puerto 8080

**Aqui se configura el socket.io**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

app.use('port', process.env.PORT || 8080) 
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), ()=>{
   console.log(`Servidor corriendo en el puerto ${app.get('port')}`)
})

const io = socketIO(server);
io.on('connection', (data)=>{
   console.log('conexion de socket exitosa')
})
```

//prueba con esta configuración y responde si no te ah funcionado, en mi opinión la razón por la que no reconoce al socket es por que no sabe en que puerto esta escuchando el servidor y no tiene comunicación

Comment: Hola Enzo, en muchos servicios el puerto es el 3000 pero no había pensado en eso, capaz si no está el port en env simplemente podría averiguarlo con su proveedor de servicios.

Comment: coloque el puerto 8080 por que la persona que hizo la pregunta lo utilizo, yo siempre uso el puerto 3000 pero para esta respuesta use el puerto que se utiliza en la pregunta

Comment: Traté de modificarlo para poner esos parámetros, pero creo que no supe cómo hacerlo... Estoy en proceso para ver qué pasa.
Gracias por la ayuda y tiempo dedicado :)